# Qt Creator undefined socket - Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sockets

I am trying to make a server/client application and I am also trying to design a GUI interface for the client in QT. Now, I have managed to make sockets using the library . However, when I write the code into Qt Creator, it's saying that sockaddr_in was undefined even though I've included the library.(when I compile the code on linux with g++ it works fine) What could be the problem?

This is how I declare the socket: sockaddr_in server;

EDIT: It might be with QT Creator not having the g++ compiler? If that might be the case, how do I add it ? I am sorry but I am quite new to QT and programming in general

I am using a "Start" button to start my application and this is the code inside it:

```
void MainWindow::on_StartButton_clicked()
{
       int port;
       port=portiuse;
       int clientsd;
       sockaddr_in server;

       if ( ( clientsd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) ) == -1 )
       {
           perror("[client]Error\n");
           return errno;
      }

      bzero (&server, sizeof (server));

   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
   server.sin_port = htons (port);

   if( ( connect(clientsd, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof (struct sockaddr) ) ) == -1 )
   {
       perror("[client]Error()\n");
       return errno;
   }
```

}

And these are the errors I get:

error: 'sockaddr_in' was not declared in this scope
        sockaddr_in server;
        ^

error: 'server' was not declared in this scope
        bzero (&server, sizeof (server));
                ^

error: 'inet_addr' was not declared in this scope
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
                                                      ^

Comment: You should post a [mcve] of the problem code, and your exact compile/link commands, as well as the error messages.  Without those, it's very hard to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: So you mean you encountered this problem on platform other than linux? If so, what platform is giving you the grief now? Is it still a g++ compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say you've "*included the library*", do you mean including `<netinet/in.h>`?

And QtCreator is indeed an IDE. It needs to know (or be told) where to find it's toolchains and compiler. You can check this under "Options", "Build & Run" with tabs for the Qt versions, Compilers, etc. Typically, it would autodetect GCC.

But I guess it is compiling, since you got an error about sockin_addr being undefined. Otherwise, just try and build a simple "hello world" first.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it, I was just dumb and forgot to add one include. Thanks everyone for the help